# How to get value from declaration only once?

Tags: c++

Say I have a function that I want to call multiple times. At the start of this function I have declared an integer for a value of zero, and at the end of it I increased its value by one. Now I want to save the new value so when I call the function again the value of that variable becomes 2. Is there a way to do that besides getting the variable from another function or declare it at the top of line codes out of the functions?

Comment: Can you put up the sample code relevant to your question description for more clarity?

Comment: Did you try the static local variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a static variable declared inside the function, since it is `static` the initialization to zero will happen only once and the rest of the time you call the function it will retain its value...

here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int x)
{
    static int counter{0};
    std::cout<< "this is x: " << x << std::endl;
    counter++;
    std::cout<< "this is counter: " << counter << std::endl;
    
}
int main() {
    foo(1);
    foo(10);
    std::cout<< "something else in the app is executed... " << std::endl;

    foo(101);

    return 0;
}
```

and here the output:

```
this is x: 1
this is counter: 1
this is x: 10
this is counter: 2
something else in the app is executed... 
this is x: 101
this is counter: 3
```

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR**
Yes, using the `static` keyword.
It changes the lifetime of the object declared with it, that becomes available for the whole duration of the program.
That said, you should be careful with using static local variables, because you're adding a state to the function execution.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void printX()
{
    static int x;
    
    cout << "x: " << x << endl;
    ++x;
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        printX();
}
```

https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/909

---

**There's more to the static keyword and you should look into it.**
I'd suggest you read at least a couple of articles about it:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_(keyword)#Common_C
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-variables-in-c/